# How to ensure the iteration will converge when train the NetWork

Tags: neural-networks

Let's generate some points for test

```
disk1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi/4}];
disk2 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/4, 3 Pi/4}];
disk3 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {3 Pi/4, 5 Pi/4}];
disk4 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {5 Pi/4, 2 Pi}];
pts = RandomPoint[#, RandomInteger[{30, 40}]] & /@ {disk1, disk2, 
    disk3, disk4};
Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], 
  Flatten@MapAt[Point, 
    Flatten[{{Red, Green, Blue, Black}, pts}, {{2}, {1}}], {All, 2}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is the train sets

```
data = RandomSample[Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[pts -> Range[4]]]];
```

This is a `net` I build to classify those points

```
net = NetGraph[{4, Ramp, 
   SoftmaxLayer[
    "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {1, 2, 3, 4}}]]}, {1 -> 2 -> 3}, 
  "Input" -> 2]
```

[image]

Let's trained it

```
trainedNet = 
 NetTrain[net, data, ValidationSet -> Scaled[.2], 
  TargetDevice -> "GPU"]
```

[image]

As the *Training Progress*, I will should have a good result.But actually not..

```
ContourPlot[trainedNet[{x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], 
   Flatten@MapAt[Point, 
     Flatten[{{Red, Green, Blue, Black}, pts}, {{2}, {1}}], {All,2}]}]
```

[image]

As you see, I get a very bad trained NetWork

But,because of the initial values is random value, sometimes I can get a very good result like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course we always hope to get a good trained result. Can anyone can give some advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is because of the `Ramp` before the `SoftmaxLayer`. Usually, we don't use activation function for the last linear layer. After removing the `Ramp`, your network will be more stable. I get 10 out of 10 correct clusterings after this modification.

```
net = NetGraph[{4, 
   SoftmaxLayer[
    "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {1, 2, 3, 4}}]]}, {1 -> 2}, 
  "Input" -> 2]
```